# Rails translations issue with i18n-js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm using http://github.com/fnando/i18n-js gem for JavaScript translation. Here is my translation yml:

```
en:
  js:
    test: "<strong>%{name}</strong> created this board."
```

In my JS, I run with "name" param is "$&".

```
console.log(I18n.t('js.test', {name: "$&"}))
```

Unfortunately, it will show message like this: **%{name}** created this board, while I expect that message should be: **$&** created this board.
Is there any problem with special character like "&" with this gem? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, your interpolation is not working as you used `%{name}` in your translation file. You have to use: `{{name}}` instead to make the interpolation work.

So, change:

```
test: "<strong>%{name}</strong> created this board."
```

to this:

```
test: "<strong>{{name}}</strong> created this board."
```

and it should work!

Comment: well, unfortunately, I use your solution and now it will show message like this: <strong>{{name}}</strong> created this board. Could you check this again? Thanks.

Comment: Try without the double quotes `""` and `<strong>`, see if that works first: `test: {{name}} created this board.`

Comment: Well, now it throws translation error: did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping.

Comment: How about: `test: "{{name}} created this board."`
and pass something simple in name like `John`

Comment: Actually, something simple like this always works very well. But in my case,    it's a word with special character "$&" and it doesn't work.

Comment: try with escape character like this: `\$\&`

Comment: Try: `console.log(I18n.t('js.test', {name: "\$\&"}))`

Comment: well, it doesn't still work :(. Moreover, "$&" is the name that is got from database.